# Unable to connect to port 8000 on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, port, django, ufw

**Description**

I am using a virtual machine with the Ubuntu image. I tried to run my server on Django with this command
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

When I search `<public ip>:8000` it fails to load.

**Inbound Port rules**

[Port Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyosZ.png)

**Firewall**

I used this tutorial for my firewall: https://youtu.be/Sa_kQheCnds?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&t=1632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only allowed incoming traffic to port 8000 from a single IP address. It looks like you put your Azure VM's IP address in as the source. So only the VM can access itself on port 8080.

You need to be loading the web app from that IP address, or change the IP address to your actual IP address, or allow any source.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [Michael](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton)'s answer, please keep in mind that Network Security Groups only affect *Azure*.

You'll also need to allow inbound traffic in your VM's local firewall.

Comment: How would I accomplish that?

Comment: does ufw allow traffic?

Comment: Yes, you can use ufw to set up a host firewall, but the last time I checked Ubuntu does not enable a host firewall by default.